# C# Windows Form Login Program

Tags: c#

Im looking to create a simple windows login form i have the files loading form a text file on my c drive, but when i compare the string the the list i have create and its not working correctly this is my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string f = "C:/Users.txt";

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        string userNameInput = Convert.ToString(userBox);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lines[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(userNameInput);
            if (lines[i] == userNameInput)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("correct");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Correct");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `lines[i]` will be having crlf at the end, so you will need to trim it. Also [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) is one line code to open read and close the file.

Comment: Would it be easier to open read do what i have to do and then close ?

Comment: @bansi It appears that is not necessarily the case - I'm reading the contents of a text file the same way. The strings added to the lines collection _do not_ actually have line breaks at the end.

Comment: @user2552211 what is userBox? if it is TextBox you need to get Text property of it, and are you get any message from your program?

Comment: @damith Whats the best way to obtain the test property, im fairly new at all this

Comment: @user2552211 `line = r.ReadLine()` will read till it finds a `crlf` or `EOF` and reads including `crlf`. It will not be same as your input text unless it also contains `crlf` at end or you have only one line in text without line break.

Comment: @damith im not receiving errors the only message that im getting is from:          MessageBox.Show(lines[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(userNameInput);

Comment: @user2552211 **Use your debugger.** This is trivial to figure out on your own if you're actually using your debugger. [Here's a tutorial for VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use the version selector under the article title if that's not your VS version.

Comment: @user2552211 Actually [this might be a better resource for teaching you about using it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Comment: @bansi, Please see [StreamReader.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) where it says `The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below

```
if (File.ReadAllLines("C:/Users.txt").Select(x=>x.Trim()).Contains(userBox.Text.Trim()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("correct");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Correct");
}
```

What it does is read all lines from your file and trim each line and compare with input text. if there is matching line you will receive message as correct

Answer (score 1):

You could simply a bit with:

```
        const string f = @"C:\Users.txt";
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(f);
        if (Array.IndexOf(lines, userBox.Text) != -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("correct");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Correct");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use this?

```
string userNameInput = Convert.ToString(userBox);
```

This could be used and is easier to get the text of the textBox by its self.

```
string userNameInput = userBox.text;
```

And this should should help with what you need.

```
const string f = "C:/Users.txt";
string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f);

string[] strings = Regex.Split(file.TrimEnd(), @"\r\n");

foreach (String str in strings)
{
    // Do something with the string. Each string comes in one at a time.
    // So this will be run like for but is simple, and easy for one object.
    // str = the string of the line.
    // I shall let you learn the rest it is fairly easy. here is one tip
    lines.Add(str);
}
// So something with lines list
```

I hope I had helped!

Comment: i didn't realize you were able to do this string userNameInput = userBox.text; thank you for your help